# Interior points and closure

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $A$ be a subset of the metric space $(X,d)$. Is it true that $$\left(\left(A'\right)'\right)'\ =\left(A'\right)' \tag{1}$$where $A'$ denotes the set of the limit points?
> Assuming that $(1)$ is true, can we prove the following equations?$$X\setminus A^\circ = \overline{X\setminus A} \tag{2}$$ $$\\ X\setminus\overline{A} = (X \setminus A)^\circ \tag{3}$$Note that $A^\circ$ denotes the interior points of $A$.

**My try:** For proving $(1)$, I tried to use $(A')'\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$ which implies $\left(\left(A'\right)'\right)' \subseteq \operatorname{cl}A'$ but I couldn't continue.

If $A$ be a finite subset then both sides of the equation are $\emptyset$, so the assumption is true. Also $A^\circ = \emptyset$ which implies $X\setminus A^\circ = X$. Using the fact $\overline{X\setminus A}\subseteq \overline{X}\setminus \overline{A}$ and $\overline{X} = X,\overline{A} = A$ we get $X\subseteq X\setminus A$ which is false, so $(2)$ is incorrect.

I tried to use the same example for $(3)$. Since $A = \overline{A}$ we have $X\setminus A = (X\setminus A)^\circ$ which shows $X\setminus A$ is open. We know that $X$ and $A$ are closed set, so if we can show that a closed set minus another closed set can't be open, then we can disprove $(3)$.

**Edit:** Thanks to Berci, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are proved in general. The only remaining problem is $(1)$.

Comment: (2) and (3) don't require (1), they follow directly from the definitions (of closure and internal points). In certain metric spaces, a finite set can be open, e.g. in $\Bbb Z$ with the usual metric. Also, the complement of a closed set is always open.

Comment: Interior of a finite set is not necessarily empty.

Comment: @Berci Thanks. How can we prove them? Also is $(1)$ correct for all subsets?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I see. According to the Berci's comment, $(2)$ holds in general. So how could be metric spaces such that interior of a finite set is empty(which shows $(2)$ doesn't hold in general)?

Comment: You have used a wrong property. Note that $X\setminus\bar A\subseteq X\setminus A\subseteq\overline{X\setminus A}$ since $A\subseteq\bar A$. So even with finite sets with empty interior you will not get a contradiction of $2$. In fact both $2,3$ are true in general.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks, you're right and my argument is really flawed. How can we prove $(2)$ and $(3)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are metric spaces with finite open sets (e.g. the discrete metric on any set).

Also, the complement of a closed set is always open.

(2) and (3) follow directly from the definitions:
$x\in X\setminus A^\circ$ means that every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ is not entirely in $A$, that is, intersects $X\setminus A$. 
And the closure $\overline B$ of any set $B$ consists exactly of those points $x$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $B$.

Similarly, $x\in X\setminus\overline A$ means that there's a neighborhood of $x$ which doesn't intersect $A$, that is, it's fully in $X\setminus A$.

Comment: I don't know if (1) is true or not..

Comment: Thanks for your answer.